# Extracting HTML string within XML tag with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, regex, sharepoint

I've been working at this for a week and I'm stumped.

I'm trying to parse an RSS feed from SharePoint using jQuery. Using `$.find` works great on extracting the data between valid XML tags in the feed, but unfortunately one of the tags  stores several HTML tags instead of the nice and clean strings like the others.

I have the tag extracted and stored as a string using the following:

```
$(xml).find("item").each(function () {
var description = $(this).find('description').text();
})
```

Which gives me the contents of the description tag:

```
<![CDATA[<div><b>Title:</b> Welcome!</div>
<div><b>Modified:</b> 6/10/2014 7:58 AM</div>
<div><b>Created:</b> 6/3/2014 2:55 PM</div>
<div><b>Created By:</b> John Smith</div>
<div><b>Modified By:</b> Samuel Smith</div>
<div><b>Version:</b> 1.0</div>
<div><b>AlertContent:</b> Stop the presses.</div>
<div><b>Team:</b> USA.</div>]]>
```

Now my problem is extracting and storing the useful bits. Is there a way to only extract the text following `AlertContent:</b>`? It seems this might be possible using regular expressions, but I don't know how to make a filter that would start at the end of the bold tag and extend all the way until the start of the closing `div` tag. Or is there a better way through jQuery's methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you're quite right; regular expressions can help you do that. Here is how you can do it:

```
var alertContent = description.replace(/^.*AlertContent:</b>([^<]*).*$/i, '$1');
```

[**WORKING JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/g4V3G/)

Comment: You're amazing! I tweaked it just a bit and used $.match. Best of all, your regex works on all of the fields.

`var alertContent = description.match(/.*AlertContent:<\/b>.([^<]*).*/i);`

Comment: Great! Glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've heard the warnings about parsing xml with regex. Nevertheless, in case you'd like to know how to do it with regex, this simple pattern will do it:

```
AlertContent:<\/b>([^<]*)
```

- We start by matching `AlertContent:</b>`
- Then the negative character class `[^<]*` matches all characters that are not a `<` and the parentheses capture them to Group 1

All we need to do is read Group 1. Here is sample code to do it:

```
var regex = /AlertContent:<\/b>([^<]*)/;
var match = regex.exec(string);
if (match != null) {
    alert = match[1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I had no idea regex was so powerful. Time to learn!